# How to add Database in project(C# App) such that it should co-exist with code exe on Customer Site and we can set the path in connection string

Tags: c#, oledb

I want to add OleDb(MS Access DB) to My Project(C# App) and Deploy it to Customer .The Db Should be installed with exe's and dll's such that we can obtain the path of DB,Write Data to it.
I really want the code where we can get the path of DB and for Connection String

Answer (score 0):

In main exe use path in connection string as:

```
Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),"DB.mdb")
```

for dll use `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location` if it is in different folder otherwise above will also work.